# How to show that $E\left[ \int_0^t \sigma(s) e^{iuX(s)} dW(s)\right] = 0$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, itos-lemma

Let $\sigma(t)$ be a given deterministic function of time and define the
process $X_t$ by
$$X(t) = \int_0^t \sigma(s)dW(s)$$ 
 I want to show  $$E\left[ \int_0^t \sigma(s) e^{iuX(s)} dW(s)\right] = 0$$

It is part of exercise 4.3 in Bjork "Arbitrage Theory in continuous time", and you can see the solution here:

[image]

The solution does not explain it.

Comment: Where did you get that solution from? You should cite your source.

Comment: If you were not looking for a proof, then you can use Proposotion 4.4 in Bjork, Arbitrage Theory in Continous time.

Answer (score 4):

**Some basic details**

$\quad$ The Itô integral can be defined in a manner similar to the Riemann–Stieltjes integral, that is as a limit in probability of Riemann sums; such a limit does not necessarily exist pathwise. Suppose that $W_t$ is a Wiener process and that $\sigma_t$ is a right-continuous (cadlag), adapted and locally bounded process if $I=\{t_0,t_1,\cdots,t_n\}$ is a sequence of partitions of $[0,t]$  with mesh going to zero, then the Itô integral of $\sigma_t$ with respect to $W_t$ up to time t is a random variable
$$X_t=\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(s)dW_s=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma(t_{i-1})(W(t_i)-W(t_{i-1}))$$
since $\sigma(s)$ is deterministic process and $W({t_i})-W(t_{i-1})\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t_i-t_{i-1})$ , thus $X_t$ is normally distributed such that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_t]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma(t_{i-1})(W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})\right]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma(t_{i-1})(W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})\right]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left[\sigma(t_{i-1})(W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})\right]\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma(t_{i-1})\mathbb{E}\left[W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}}\right]\\
&=0 .
\end{align*}
By application of [Ito's isometry formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry), we have
$$\text{Var}(X_t)=\text{Var}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(s)dW_s\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_{0}^{t}\sigma(s)dW_s\right)^2\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t}\sigma^2_sds\right]=\int_{0}^{t}\sigma^2_sds$$

---

**Proof**

If $Y(t)$ be a regular adapted process such that $\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}\left[ Y^2(s)\right]ds < \infty$ then
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t}Y(s)dW_s\right]=0$$
Set $Y(s)=\sigma(s) e^{iuX(s)} $, we have
$$\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}\left[ Y^2(s)\right]ds=\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}\left[ \sigma^2(s) e^{2iuX(s)}\right]ds=\int_{0}^{t}\sigma^2(s)\mathbb{E} \left[ e^{2iuX(s)}\right]ds\tag 1$$
$X(t)$ is normally distributed with zero mean and a variance given by
$$\text{Var}(X_s)=\int_{0}^{s}\sigma^2(v)dv$$
thus
$$\mathbb{E} \left[ e^{2iuX(s)}\right]=\exp\left(2\text{i}\,u\,\mathbb{E}[X_s]-2u^2\text{Var}(X_s)\right)\tag 2$$

As a result
$$\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}\left[ Y^2(s)\right]ds=\int_{0}^{t}\sigma^2(s)\exp\left(-2u^2\int_{0}^{s}\sigma^2(v)dv\right)ds<\infty$$

Comment: Let $\sigma(t)$ has good properties ;)

Comment: What a terrible answer! In order to show that $\int_0^t E[Y^2(S)]ds < \infty$, you use that $X$ is normally distributed, with mean $0$ and variance $\int_0^s \sigma^2(v)dv$. Yet, you give NO argument for these claims.

Comment: @Jin5: This is a perfectly valid answer that uses the basic property that an Ito integral of a deterministic integrand is normally distributed. A better comment would have been to ask for clarification if this isn't clear to you. See e.g. Theorem 4.4.9 in Shreve's "Stochastic Calculus for Finance II".

Comment: @LocalVolatility What a load of nonsense. The point of the exercise is precisely to SHOW this result. Read the original question where there is a link the exercise solution. I don't give a damn how basic of a property it is, you can't use a basic result in the very proof of that result! I cannot even believe that I have to exlain this obvious concept to you. I repeat: the exercise ASKS for a proof that the Ito integral of a deterministic integrand is normally distributed. You can't bloody use that fact in the answer to the exercise!

Comment: Please keep it civil. We have a 'be nice'-policy and that policy is enforced.

Comment: @Jin5: Take it easy. The question asks to show why the expectation of the given Ito integral is zero. Behrouz Maleki states the condition for which an Ito integral is a martingale and then shows that this is indeed satisfied here. From the way I understand Maaniya's question, this link between square-integrability and the martingale property of the Ito integral is exactly the step that was missing in the provided sample solution.